# VCalendar and PHP sending meeting request but email is not requesting a reply

Tags: php, icalendar, vcalendar, vcal

I am using PHP and VCal to send a meeting request to a user. The issue is, when the use receives the request, it does not give them the option to "Accept/Decline" the meeting. This is happening in OUTLOOK. The accept and decline button options are greyed out and the when the email is opened it says "No response required" I would like to make it so that the user has the option to decline or accept and DOES require a response. If I try to accept a test invite on my iphone, a message pops up that says "Your response to the invitation cannot be sent." Not sure what tweak I need to make in my VCAL code. Any idea?

EDIT TO POST: I figured out how to make the calendar event allow for accepting and denying caldendar invites by changing the 'METHOD:PUBLISH' instead of request.

EDITED ISSUE: Now the issue I am running into is that the user receiving the Vcalendar invite is able to edit the subject, and location and date of the event. How do I disable the ability to edit Calendar Invite details using VCal?

Thank you.

```
  //Create Email Headers
        $mime_boundary = "----Meeting Booking----".MD5(TIME());

    $headers = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$mime_boundary\"\n";
    $headers .= "Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage\n";

    //Create Email Body (HTML)
    $message = "--$mime_boundary\r\n";
    $message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
    $message .= "<html>\n";
    $message .= "<body>\n";
    $message .= '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
    $message .= "</body>\n";
    $message .= "</html>\n";
    $message .= "--$mime_boundary\r\n";

    $ical =
        'BEGIN:VCALENDAR' . "\r\n" .
        'PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 16.0 MIMEDIR//EN' . "\r\n" .
        'CALSCALE:GREGORIAN' . "\r\n" .
        'VERSION:2.0' . "\r\n" .
        'METHOD:REQUEST' . "\r\n" .
        'BEGIN:VTIMEZONE' . "\r\n" .
        'TZID:America/Chicago:' . "\r\n" .
        'BEGIN:STANDARD' . "\r\n" .
        'DTSTART:200911 01T020000' . "\r\n" .
        'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11' . "\r\n" .
        'TZOFFSETFROM:-0400' . "\r\n" .
        'TZOFFSETTO:-0500' . "\r\n" .
        'TZNAME:EST' . "\r\n" .
        'END:STANDARD' . "\r\n" .
        'BEGIN:DAYLIGHT' . "\r\n" .
        'DTSTART:20090301T020000' . "\r\n" .
        'RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3' . "\r\n" .
        'TZOFFSETFROM:-0500' . "\r\n" .
        'TZOFFSETTO:-0400' . "\r\n" .
        'TZNAME:EDST' . "\r\n" .
        'END:DAYLIGHT' . "\r\n" .
        'END:VTIMEZONE' . "\r\n" .
        'BEGIN:VEVENT' . "\r\n" .
        'ORGANIZER;CN="'.$from_name.'":MAILTO:'.$from_address. "\r\n" .
         //'ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN="'.$to_name.'";'.
        'ATTENDEE;CN="'.$to_name.'";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:'.$to_address. "\r\n" .
        'LAST-MODIFIED:' . date("Ymd\TGis") . "\r\n" .
        'UID:'.date("Ymd\TGis", strtotime($startTime)).rand()."@".$domain."\r\n" .
        'DTSTAMP:'.date("Ymd\TGis"). "\r\n" .
        'DTSTART;TZID="Eastern Time":'.date("Ymd\THis", strtotime($startTime)). "\r\n" .
        'DTEND;TZID="Eastern Time":'.date("Ymd\THis", strtotime($endTime)). "\r\n" .
        'TRANSP:OPAQUE'. "\r\n" .
        'SEQUENCE:1'. "\r\n" .
        'SUMMARY:' . $subject . "\r\n" .
        'LOCATION:' . $location . "\r\n" .
        'CLASS:PUBLIC'. "\r\n" .
        'PRIORITY:5'. "\r\n" .
        'BEGIN:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
        'TRIGGER:-PT15M' . "\r\n" .
        'ACTION:DISPLAY' . "\r\n" .
        'DESCRIPTION:Reminder' . "\r\n" .
        'END:VALARM' . "\r\n" .
        'END:VEVENT'. "\r\n" .
        'END:VCALENDAR'. "\r\n";
    $message .= 'Content-Type: text/calendar;name="meeting.ics";method=REQUEST'."\n";
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
    $message .= $ical;

    $mailsent = mail($to_address, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: JUST FYI: If I keep the METHOD as REQUEST, when the invite is received and I try to accept the invite, I get the error message of "Your response to the invitation cannot be sent." Any work around for this?

Comment: One thing that's at least wrong is that your TZID refers to "Eastern time", but the VTIMEZONE object you're embedding is "America/Chicago". These 2 strings need to match. I also noticed that the DTSTART in VTIMEZONE is badly formatted. There might be other problems, but those would definitely not help.

Comment: What should my time be instead of Eastern Time? Also, how should I format my DTSTART? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The TZID string can be anything you want, but it needs to match with the information in `VTIMEZONE`. For more information on formatting iCalendar, check the standard: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545

I would suggesting using olsen strings though, like "America/New_York" and "America/Chicago", but again the point is that they need to match.

Comment: There are libraries out there for PHP that help you generate correctly formatted VCALENDAR Objects. Might help.

Comment: Any specific libraries you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

The line starting with `ATTENDEE` defines the information required to respond to the request. In your code, it looks strange:

```
'ATTENDEE;CN="'.$to_name.'";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:'.$to_address. "\r\n"
```

As far as I know, the `:MAILTO` part belongs to the CN. Here's a line from an iCal file that works properly in Outlook and on iPhone:

```
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=Peter:MAILTO:peter@pan.com
```

The e-mail address needs to be the address of the recipient of your request, not yours (obviously).